# .NET Core project does not have a lock file on docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am creating a docker file based on *cl0sey/dotnet-mono-node-docker:latest* to build my .NET Core solution. The solution folder is under a folder called *src*.

When I execute

```
dotnet restore -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

I get no exception, all seems to go well and I get the corresponding verification for all projects that the **project.lock.json** files have been created, like

> log  : Writing lock file to disk. Path:
>   /build/src/CoreLibrary/src/CoreWeb/project.lock.json

, but when I invoke

```
dotnet build ./src/**/project.json -c Release
```

I get the following error:

> Project x does not have a lock file. Please run "dotnet restore" to
>   generate a new lock file.

I've checked with `find . -type f` and found that the lock files are indeed missing, despite the trace message stated otherwise. Interestingly if I do the very same steps on my local windows, it works like a charm.

**Update:** I experience the same behavior using *microsoft/dotnet:latest* as a base image.

Comment: Any reason you want to use mono instead of the .NET core images?

Comment: @R0MANARMY Hi, not at this point, so if you think using a different base image please advice. In time, I'll need to build xprojs as well as normal .NET projects for my CI, so I'll need both the dotnet cli tool and xbuild. I just don't think it'll work properly for any other image if it doesn't work as expected for the cl0sey/dotnet-mono-node-docker:latest.

Comment: @R0MANARMY I've double checked and experience the same if using microsoft/dotnet:latest. Updated the question.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue... any updates on this?... I'm using microsoft/dotnet(:latest)...

Comment: @MauriceCGPPeters does your docker file define volumes?